# Code Mirror for JS Based Scripting Language

Tags: codemirror

I am using Code Mirror for SuiteScript Editing. This scripting language is an extended version of Javascript. I need following features in the editor

- Code Hints for API functions like native javascript functions.
- Many functions are called from objects but Code Hints don't work after dot (eg. myObj.apiFunc ) as it works after blank space
- Code hints from header files (as these files will not be a part of content itself but global variables and functions defined in header files can be accessed as code hints)

Can these features be added without modifying the core Code Mirror as I don't want to mess up with the core Code Mirror Code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need code hints with [type inferencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).  Have you checked out [Tern](http://ternjs.net/), a new code hinting engine written by the creator of CodeMirror?